# Browserify multiple files into a single bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Currently, I browserify a single js file into a bundle.js

```
$ browserify X1.js --standalone XXX > bundle.js
```

What if I have multiple js files and want to join them into a single browserified bundle.js

How should the command look like? Can I do something like this?

```
$ browserify X1.js X2.js --standalone XXX > bundle.js
```

I am using node.js v6

Comment: Which task runner you are using ?

Comment: I am not using any task runner. I am just running the command on a normal Windows command prompt.

Comment: Based on the syntax of their documentation: `browserify [entry files] {OPTIONS}`, yes, you can add as many files as you want like you are doing in your second command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have already answered your own question. I confirm that it is correct.

```
$ browserify X1.js X2.js --standalone XXX > bundle.js
```

Comment: Similar should be the o flag: `browserify X1.js X2.js -o bundle.js`.

Answer (score 2):

If your command line supports expansion, you can use `*` to include all files in a directory:

```sh
$ browserify *.js --standalone XXX > distribution/bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the browserify command to build a bundle

```
 $ browserify X1.js X2.js > bundle.js
```