# Minimal number of commands to produce a client-side ready-to-use Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

For many JS libraries we can find on Github, it's nowadays impossible to use them directly in a client-side project by doing:

```
<script src="thelibrary.js"></script>
```

The browser won't accept the `require` and other Node-related keywords that are present both in [fernet.js](https://github.com/csquared/fernet.js/blob/master/fernet.js) and even in [fernetBrowser.js](https://github.com/csquared/fernet.js/blob/master/fernetBrowser.js).

I have read a few tutorials here are there that suggest to install `Node` (with `npm`), then `browserify` or `webpack` and also a transpiler, etc. but before installing any new software, I usually make sure it's absolutely needed to understand well how it works.

**Question: what is the minimum number of command-line commands to have to run to be able to turn a .js using `require` (such as [fernetBrowser.js](https://github.com/csquared/fernet.js/blob/master/fernetBrowser.js)) into a .js file loadable directly in a browser on client-side?**

Comment: `fernetBrowser.js` will work in browser, its using a umd wrapper. anyways, using something like [parceljs](https://parceljs.org/) to answer your question 1 cmd.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I see `Run parcel index.html to start a dev server. Importing JavaScript, CSS, images, and more just works!`: will this recreate new JS files so that we can use it these files on a standard server *without* parcel installed? Maybe could you post an answer with it? And also a note about umd wrapper, would be interesting for future reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually a javascript package also includes a minified build for the browser (if applicable). These files can be copied to the document root/public path of your application in a simple build pipeline. You could even install/symlink them directly to node_modules in the public path. I do not think that it is impossible.

Comment: Interesting note about UMD / AMD / CommonJS: https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the file is ready for use in a browser environment, because it has been built with browserify in order to copy all of the libraries and map them to their path (e.g: `'crypto-js/aes'`). Browserify also adds some boilerplate code that enables the browser to work with the CommonJS syntax (`require` and `module.exports`).

So to answer your question, the minimal number of commands to run, in order to create a browser-ready package from a file using CommonJS imports is **one**, since the only task to perform is to bundle the code and its dependencies into a single file (+ also install the dependencies):

```
npm i -g browserify  # once for all
npm i
browserify -s fernet fernet.js > fernetBrowser.js
```

Optionally, for a production-ready file, you could also use a minifier, like [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) in order to serve the smaller possible JavaScript file (and obfuscate your code at the same time).

If there are multiple JS files to bundle, here is an answer: [Browserify multiple files into a single bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484355/browserify-multiple-files-into-a-single-bundle)

Comment: What you're missing is the `package.json` file from this project. You'll find all of the dependencies, installable with `npm i` and also the build command `browserify -s fernet fernet.js > fernetBrowser.js`. If you count `npm i` then there are two commands

Comment: I tried `npm i` and `browserify ...` commands. It works. But then if I move (or just rename) `/node_modules/` then the page `test.html` doesn't work anymore because it cannot find some files: this shows that **not everything** is packed into a single .js.  How to use `browserify` to pack everything into a single .js such that even if we remove the `/node_modules/` folder, it still works?

Comment: Your `index.html` has a reference on the generated `fernetBrowser.js`?

Comment: Yes, idem if I reference to bundled.js

Comment: I'm sorry but it works for me, did you `npm i -g browserify`?

Comment: Here is what I did: `npm install -g browserify` (once for all). Then `git clone https://github.com/csquared/fernet.js.git`, go in this folder, then `npm i`, then `browserify -s fernet fernet.js > fernetBrowser.js`. Then open `test.html` in your browser: it fails (the code is still looking for `node_modules/<fileshere>`).

Comment: That's exactly what I did too. My `index.html` contains `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="fernetBrowser.js"></script>
</body>
</html>` and when I open it, there is an actual `fernet` function in the global scope, and no errors at all

Comment: Useful if many JS files to pack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484355/browserify-multiple-files-into-a-single-bundle